# Почему android-studio не видит папку layout-large?

Tags: android-studio

Создаю папку layout-large. Android-studio не показывает ее в режиме Android. В режиме Packages показывает. В коде активити папка layout-large также не распознается и макеты из нее не распознаются. Как побороть эту беду?

Comment: Если вы нашли это в каком-то курсе или книге. Советую бросить и найти что-то современнее. Хотя бы с версией Android 4.2+

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`layout-large` с версии Android 3.2 был удалён, также как и `layout-xlarge` и прочие.

Если вам нужен `layout-large`, то используйте `layout-sw600dp`.

Больше информации в официальной [документации](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html).